# How to disable Cut|Copy|Replace|Share etc popup on mobile?

Tags: ios, html, responsive-design, summernote

I have a rich text editor (summer note), and on ios it's almost impossible to do anything. As you select any text you get the ios popup that never goes away. How to prevent it?

One option is to use `user-select` like this:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;    
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

However, it will disable text selection altogether. I just want to hide the options pop up.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried the `-webkit-touch-callout: none;` property on the text editor element?

Comment: yea I did. that didnt work. :)